# How to Phpstorm reindent if(not)

Tags: phpstorm

```
if(!true){
   return 'wrong';
}
```

How to set reindent become to likes below ? psr

```
if(! true){
   return 'wrong';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP`
2. `Spaces` tab
3. `Other | After unary Not(!)` option